# Bidding for a new skill (without any history)

Tags: attracting-clients, marketing, communication

I have learned new skills and I want to apply for jobs, the question is how do I manage when writing a cover letter.how do I give them example? Even If I am contacted back. How do I tell them I don't have any previous projects. How do I satisfy and get the job.

Answer (score 5):

Don't be a guy with no projects. Projects don't have to be paid ones. Have you created projects during the learning phase? You must have had so put those into portfolio.

Also create a few more projects with that skill and put in the portfolio.

Clients don't care much if you had paid projects. They need to see projects to see what your skill are.